# I am non-EU citizen working in Germany. Can I travel to UK without a visa?

Tags: visas, uk, german-residents

I am from Non-EU country (from Nepal to be precise) and recently moved to Germany for work. I am applying for BlueCard. I would like to travel to UK later this year, can I go there without visa as I am resident in another EU country?

I can't find this information online. Any links/references will be much appreciated.

Comment: check: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa.  Also please provide your citizenship.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nepalese citizens require a visa to visit the UK.

Having a residence permit from another EU/EEC country does not free you from any UK visitor visa requirements. A residence permit from an EU/EEC country may free you from transit visa requirements. I would however assume that a EU residence permit will ease the application process and make it more probable that your application will be granted.

Comment: (+1) Having an EEA residence permit does free the holder from the DATV requirement so it would be more accurate to write that it does not free you from the requirement to have a visa to visit the UK.

Comment: You are right, I forgot about the transit visa exceptions. I have modified the answer.

Comment: Precisely. In fact, a Schengen visa or residence permit does not grant you access even to territories like Greenland or Faroe Islands, although they're a part of the Kingdom of Denmark, whereas some countries like Mexico waive the visa requirements from people with Schengen residence permits.

Answer (score 4):

The UK is not part of the Schengen-zone, but part of the Common Travel Area. To enter the latter you might need to get a visa, depending on your nationality. You will probably need to obtain a [General Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/general-visit-visa).

You can check if you need a visa, and what type you need on the government's [visa checker site](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa).

Comment: Ummmmm....  What if the OP is Canadian or a US citizen?

Comment: @Karlson is right, the OP nationality is important, in this case the OP is Indian

Comment: @Karlson I think that is addressed in "you **might** need to get a visa, **depending** on your nationality"

Comment: I am from Nepal. I updated question to make it clear.

Comment: That visa checker site is totally useless for me. It only asks for nationality, which isn't what I am looking information for. Anyways, it seems I need to get visa. Damn!

Comment: "You might need a visa" is a rather pointless answer to the question "do I need a visa?". Except for that, a visa is issued by either UK or Ireland and not for the CTA. Having a UK visa does not necessarily entitle you to go to Ireland and vice versa, although both countries are in the CTA.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo “You might need a visa, depending on your nationality” means exactly the same thing than the second sentence of your answer (i.e. EU residents are not automatically freed from all visa requirements in other EU countries). It's far from pointless.

Answer (score 1):

#### You will need a visa.

From the [EU Immigration Website](http://ec.europa.eu/immigration/tab1.do?subSec=30&language=7$en#morethan):

> **Moving between EU countries during my long-term stay – more than three months**
>
> When you stay in an EU country for a long stay, usually for more than three months, you will generally be issued with a national long-stay visa and/or a residence permit.
>
> If your long-stay visa or permit has been issued by a Schengen area country, you can travel to another Schengen area country for three months per six-month period. [...]

Germany is part of [Schengen](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/index_en.htm). If you have a long-term visa in one Schengen country, you can freely visit the other 25 for up to three months without a visa.

The UK and Ireland are not part of Schengen, and thus excempt from this rule.